# My powerline do not work

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

System: Win7 professional Service Pack 1
vim version: 7.3

Hi guys, I install the powerline to my vim by copy the files to my

> d:\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\
>
> d:\Vim\vimfiles\doc\
>
> d:\Vim\vimfiles\autoload\

and set my vimrc as the github instructions: https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline
. But when I restart my vim I get the error below:

> Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*": E194:
> No alternate file name to substitute for '#':runtime
> autoload/Pl#UpdateStatusline.vim Press Enter or type command to
> continue Invalid Powerline theme! Please check your theme and
> colorscheme settings.

Answer (score 0):

That erroneous command mixes the autoload function syntax (`foo#bar()`) with the file path (`foo/bar.vim`); it should be

```
:runtime autoload/Pl/UpdateStatusline.vim
```